# My datepicker doesn't display in bootstrap modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am having form in Bootstrap. This form popups on button. In form I have input field in which I want to make jQuery datepicker. It never displays when clicking on input field

In my head I have included this files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.3.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.css">
<script src="config.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.5.1"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
```

My modal code is this

```
<!-- Modal: modalAddContract -->
<!-- Datepicker - MS-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js</script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
         <script>
 
 $(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".modal-body", function () {
   $("[data-toggle='datepicker']").datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
     parentEl: '#dispatch_modal'                           
     });
      }); 
});

           </script>
<form id="addContractForm">
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAddContract" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
    <div id="new-contract-app" class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center w-100 font-weight-bold lang" key="langAddContract"></h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="lang" key="langDevice" for="addContractFormDeviceID"></label>

          <select class="form-control" id="addContractFormDeviceID">
            <option v-for="device in vueDevices.items" :value="device.id">
              {{ device.device_type }} - {{ device.device_description }} ({{ device.id }})
            </option>
          </select>

        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="lang" key="langContractDescription" for="addContractContractDescription"></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addContractContractDescription">
        </div>

        <b><div class="lang" key="langAddContractInstrTop"></div></b><br>

        <div class="row align-items-end">  
          <div class="form-group col">
            <label class="lang" key="langDateFrom" for="addContractFormDateFrom"></label>
            <input data-toggle="datepicker" type="text" class="form-control" id="addContractFormDateFrom" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col">
            <label class="lang" key="langDateTo" for="addContractFormDateTo"></label>
            <input data-toggle="datepicker" type="text" class="form-control" id="addContractFormDateTo" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        
       

        <b><div class="lang" key="langAddContractInstrMid"></div></b><br>

        <div class="row align-items-end">
          <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label class="lang" key="langDeviceUser" for="addContractFormDeviceUser"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addContractFormDeviceUser" v-model="inputUser">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-3" style="padding-right: 0px">
            <label class="lang" key="langUserPart" for="addContractFormUserPart"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addContractFormUserPart" v-model="inputPart" onkeyup="$('#addContractFormUserPart').val($('#addContractFormUserPart').val().replace(',','.'))">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-3">
            <b-button block variant="outline-success" class="float-right lang" key="langAddUser" @click="addUser"></b-button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <ul>
          <li>{{ owner }}, delež: {{ computedPart }}</li>
          <li v-for="user in users">{{ user.email }}, delež: {{ user.usage_part }} <span v-on:click="removeUser(user)" style="color:red"><span class="lang" key="langRemove"></span> <i class="fas fa-times"></i></span></i></li>
        </ul>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary lang" key="langCancel" data-dismiss="modal" @click="resetAddContractForm"></button>
        <button id="addContractButton" type="button modal-dialog-centered" class="btn btn-primary lang" key="langAddContract" @click="addContract"></button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And also in the end of my code I have those scripts

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script
<script src="lib/mobile-nav/mobile-nav.js"></script>
<script src="lib/p2r/jquery.p2r.min.js"></script>
```

Funny is that if I create new .html file and include just tags which are within the  and only one input field my code works fine.. SO i guess there is a problem with the modal or popup.. I don't know how to fix it.. THank you

Comment: If your datetimepicker isn't displaying only in the modal, I am guessing it's a z-index issue. I have had this before where the datetimepicker doesn't show up inside a modal. It was because it was opening behind the modal. So my advice: inspect element, open the modal and click on your input, and see if stuff is happening. If the datetimepicker is opening, increase the z-index and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sadly it doesn't change anything. Even with the inspect tool on browser I can't really see if datepicker is displaying or no. I added this:
<head>
<style>
    .ui-datepicker {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}

    .datepicker {
  z-index:10800 !important;
  display: block;
}
.form-control.datepicker  {position:unset}

.form-group.datepicker  {position:unset}

</style>

Comment: Hmm, okay. Could you make a minimal jsfiddle with your issue? It'll be easier to debug.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0cz38yvu/19/
It works on my JSFiddle, but not on my page.. is there an option to contact you via Twitter and we can talk more easily?

Comment: I don't see a modal in your jsfiddle though. And maybe just comment here for now, I can't access twitter from my work place.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0cz38yvu/29/
This is correct JSFiddle.. If i delete out this line   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
 in the JavaScript Libraires datepicker works on jsfiddle, but then nothing works in my web page.. if I let this script incluet on JSFiddle even datepicker doesn't work..

Comment: You can change type="text" to type="date" in your input field. It will work... you might need to modify things accordingly I guess.

Comment: If I change to type="date" than my date promat is dd.mm.yy but for me a format YYYY-MM-DD is a must sadly

Comment: Okay, first you're including jquery and bootstrap js file twice, I cleaned up the fiddle and rearranged imports, check now: https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/5vgsxbt7/2/

Comment: Sadly in my page it doesn't work.
I will paste exactly every script i have included once again, maybe i missed something
https://jsfiddle.net/fzkb7yvr/30/

Problem is with this script: LINE 14 in html code
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS File -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Without this in JSFiddle works fine..But withou that even in my web page doesn't show datepicker and my page looks awful without this including

Comment: There must be a problem with css I guess because if i swtich type="text" to type="date" it works but not with the right format.. So I really don't know what to try anymore to fix the problem